# Calculation in an attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, attribute-table, calculate-values

I have the following attribute table:

[image: attribute table]

on which there are points on different types of lands.
Each land has a code that is in the CODE_00 field, I have calculated how many points there are in each of the lands in the NUMPOINTS field. How to calculate the total number of points in a land with code 311?

Comment: `sum("NUMPOINTS", filter:="CODE_00"=311)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "Statistics by categories" tool in the toolbox. Select the layer in which your data are (Count, I guess) and then select both the fields (attributes) you want the statistics be calculated from (NUMPOINTS) and the categories (CODE_00). Then just run the algorithm. The sum will be one of the values you'll get.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Virtual Layers:

```sql
SELECT CODE00,SUM(NUMPOINTS) AS SUM
FROM csd
where CODE00 = 311
group by CODE00
```

[image: Using the Virtual Layers:]